# Parse string containing contents from ZIP file?

Tags: javascript, zip, archive

Lets say I have a string containing the contents of a ZIP file. I want to get an array/object of the files and directories packed inside this string. What are the steps to parse this string? How does a zip file work? Would this be too slow? Would it be faster considering general internet speed, ajax, and PHP?

Thanks a lot!

*PS: Please don't point me to a library. For me there is no point in doing something if I don't know what's going on.*

Comment: How are you getting this string into javascript? Seems like it'd be rather painful one way or another.

Comment: Nitpicking: "would it be faster" need to be in comparison with something... It is also kind of hard to see what type of "faster" you mean: faster to impement or faster to execute...

Comment: I meant "faster [than] PHP and some ajax"...faster to execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [official ZIP file format specification](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) is a good starting point here. The fifth chapter (`General Format of a .ZIP file`) contains everything you have to know to parse the file/directory tree - this won't be slow if you aren't doing it wrong.

For decompressing certain files, you should read [RFC 1950](http://www.gzip.org/zlib/rfc-zlib.html) (zlib) and [RFC 1951](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1951.html) (deflate), but this is much more complicated and a good place to start using libraries.